# Raspberry Pi & Focusrite Scarlett 2i2

Tags: usb, usb-power

I'm trying to build a project which involves a Pi connected to an Arduino over USB and to a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 over USB as well. A small diaphragm condenser microphone is to be connected to the audio interface and the audio over USB is then further processed by code running on the Pi. The final output involves the Pi sending a command to the Arduino using Firmata.

Now, my question is this. How do I handle the power requirements for both the interface and the Arduino? Will the Pi be able to handle the interface by itself, in case of which, I'll power the Arduino over its own DC adapter? Or if not, is there any recommended USB hub that I can use to handle all the power requirements?

I've gone through the recommended list of peripherals and most are not available locally in India (which is where I am from, by the way) and the Pi Hub which seems to be the cleanest option again isn't available here.

Focusrite 2i2

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've tested it by changing the parameter max_usb_current=1 in /boot/config.txt.

It was able to work "out of the box" using Ubuntu Mate distribution for Raspberry Pi.