# Is the new 2nd gen Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 compatible with the RPi 3 B

Tags: usb, audio-playback

For my audio project I'm thinking about connecting a **Focusrite Scarlett 2i4** USB audio interface to a **Raspberry Pi 3 B**.
From my research, I know that the older model is [compatible](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13799/raspberry-pi-focusrite-scarlett-2i2), but is this also true for the recent 2nd generation model? I'm referring to [this model](https://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i4).

I'd be grateful for any feedback from people that have already tried this.

*Edit to add*: I'm talking about the latest model that was released in June 2016. I'd also appreciate feedback on any other model of the new Scarlett generation like the *Solo*. The internals are very probably similar and might give a clue about compatibility for the other models.

Comment: Any update? Is 2i4 2nd gen working for Linux?

Comment: Just got my Focusrite Scarlett Solo (2nd Gen). Works on both RPI 2B and RPI 3B

Comment: @ton1c Hi, sorry I had a pretty busy period and didn't see your comment.
I'm glad to see that it works. If you add this as an official answer, I will mark this as _answered_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a new Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 2nd Gen (+ Pi3B with RB Jessie) as well.

Although:

- the CL alsamixer tells me there are no controls
- no changes were made in the file alsa.conf
- Darkice (& Alsa) does not seem to be able to recognize the device

the device does work well with the application Audacity (Record and then PlayBack as well). Select in the Edit/Parameters the Scarlett as recording as well as playback device.

The device is also identified in $ cat /proc/asound/cards.

Perhaps this is not yet an answer but a clue for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have set your post as answer. This completely answers my question. All other problems will have to be clarified individually.

Answer (score 1):

User nicktate6630's [Flickr page](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nicktate/25075264393) suggests he got one up and running using ALSA, [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) and [Jack](http://www.jackaudio.org/), although he notes:

> By modifying the cmdline.txt file and replacing:
>
> ```
> dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0
> ```
>
> This will ensure audio recording works properly.

There are, however, some potential issues noted by user ym2612 [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=125629&p=842311) on the raspberrypi.org forums:

> all input via the interface was extremely noisy, with a combination of
>   static and bitcrushing

He went on to describe these issues as 'solved' by the tips in [this 2i2 related thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=125650), also on the raspberrypi.org board.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the posts seem to be from earlier this year or older. They could not have used the 2nd generation Scarletts, since they were release this June AFAIK, so the reason why I'm asking this question is to make sure the new model also works with the RPi.Since they boosted up the max supported sampling rate up to 192kHz it seems that they changed quite a bit of the internal components...
So are you sure this will also work with the new model?

Comment: Well that's a disaster, eh? I'd presumed the 2i2 was the gen 1 and the 2i4 was the gen 2, rather than there being multiple versions of each model. Per your comment, my links may not apply. I hope you get a more sensible answer - it might be tricky with such a recently released interface.

Comment: Yeah, but thanks for your infos anyway - if it works at all, I assume that similar adjustments have to be made for the new model.